# Search a Set in SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have 2 databases in completely different servers with no relationship between the two. There's one column in both databases that has identical data. I need to match based on that data so I can grab other info from both databases in one View.

Here's what I've got in my `views.py`

```
@view_config(route_name='cis', renderer='templates/cis.pt')
def cis(request):
    db1 = cis_db.query(site.site_id).join(site_tag).filter(site_tag.tag_id.like(202)).all()
    db2 = DBSession.query(A_School.cis_site_id).all()
    sites = set(db1).intersection(db2)
    return {
        'newsites': cis_db.query(site_tag).filter(site_tag.tag_id.like(202)).count(),
        'schools': DBSession.query(table).all(),
        'test': DBSession.query(table.cis_site_id.like(sites)).all(),
        }
```

My rendered page returns this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=set', 'HY105')
```

The sql code that follows has the correct numbers in it. I think the problem lies in what's returned in `sites`. Here's what the page returns immediately after that error:

```
u'SELECT [A_School].cis_site_id LIKE ? AS anon_1 
FROM [A_School]' (set([(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]),)
```

So the data returned looks correct but the leading `set` I think is throwing off the query that has `sites` in the `.like` section. Not sure how to get this working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`in_(...)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/internals.html?#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.QueryableAttribute.in_) instead of `like(sites)`?
Actually, `in_([s[0] for s in sites])` in order to unwrap the tuples from the sites set.

Comment: Getting the following error:

`ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")`

Comment: Could you shre the `SQL` statement which was generated?

Comment: Not sure why it's loading a boat load of question marks. `u'SELECT [A_School].cis_site_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) AS anon_1 
FROM [A_School]' (14639, 14587, 14966, 14625, 14589, 15144, 15171, 14590, 15134, 14719, 15150, 14704, 15153, 15096, 15133, 14036)`

It is returning correct numbers after the A_School section.

Comment: Question marks is how the parameters are passed to the engine. The way it is done depends on what the driver supports.

Comment: Can't seem to get the syntax right here. Any thoughts? Driver is `pyodbc`

Comment: tried converting to list to see what would happen. Error I keep getting is the same as before, only now `param-type=KeyedTuple`